# MATLAB convert string representing array to actual array?

Tags: arrays, string, matlab

I have the following:

```
ans = 

    '[-1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0]'
```

I really want the variable

```
x = [-1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0]
```

How can I convert `ans` into `x`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`str2num`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/str2num.html):

```
s = '[-1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0]';
x = str2num(s);
```

If your input is a cell array:

```
c = {'[-1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0]'};
x = str2num(c{1});
```

Comment: `Error using str2num (line 33)
Requires string or character array input.`

Comment: @JDS Maybe your variable is a cell: c = `{'[-1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0]'}`? In that case, use `x = str2num(c{1})`

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
a =  '[-1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0]'

x = str2num(a(2:end-1))
```